# Finding a finite spanning set for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to do a suggested practice question in my book but I don't know where to start. The question is:

Find a finite spanning set for the subspace W of P3 consisting of all polynomials of the form p(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d, where a + 2b + c = 0 and a - 2b + d= 0.

Could someone please provide a detailed explanation on solving this problem? This question is supposed to show up on my midterm so it's crucial that I should understand how to do this, but my book does not provide an answer so I can't even work the question backwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a vector space of polynomials, which by general conspiracy is called $P_3$ to mark the fact that each of is elements is determined by the values of $4$ coefficients, called $a,b,c,d$ (so $\dim(P_3)=4$). But there is a subspace $W$ of $P_3$ defined by the condition that for its elements two linear (homogeneous) equations hold. Barring exceptional circumstances (namely a dependence between the equations) the subspace$~W$ defined by these equation should be of dimension $4-2=2$.

But you are asked to describe $W$ by a finite spanning set, which means finding actual elements of $W$ (which the equations don't give you directly); moreover these should be so that *all* elements of $W$ (which is an infinite amount) can be obtained by linearly combining those elements. The name of the method to find elements in a subspace defined by a system of linear homogeneous equations is called *solving* the system. Moreover you want to describe *all* solutions (elements of$~W$), so you want an expression giving the *general form* of a solution. If you solve by the usual method, you will find that in this underdetermined system, some of the unknowns can be chosen freely, after which the other unknowns can be expressed in terms of them. For instance if $b,c$ were the freely chosen variables you would get $a=pb+qc$ and $d=rb+sc$ for some numbers $p,q,r,s$ (you should actually solve the system to find which are the freely chosen unknowns, and which are those numbers). This can be written as $(a,b,c,d)=b(p,1,0,r)+c(q,0,1,s)$. Since that is the general solution, in particular $(a,b,c,d)=(p,1,0,r)$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(q,0,1,s)$ are solutions and every solution is a linear combination of those two solutions. Which is what you were after.

Finally don't forget that $(a,b,c,d)$ actually describe a polynomial, so your spanning set would in fact consist of the two polynomials $px^3+x^2+r$ and $qx^3+x+s$.

Comment: Thank you! I need time to digest this. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello, could you please explain the general form of a solution part? What does this look like? And how do I solve it? RREF? Also, could you please explain the "where a + 2b + c = 0 and a - 2b + d= 0" in the original question? Thanks!

Comment: I meant general solution only in contrast with just finding some specific solution. So rather than choosing specific values for the free unknowns, you just use their names ($b,c$ in my example) as parameters for describing a solution. If you use RREF to solve the system, the free unknowns correspond to the non-pivot columns, while the remaining unknowns (pivot columns) are expressed in terms of them. I cannot be more concrete unless you actually give the RREF; I won't compute it for you.